# How do I import a class I made in Python and create an instance of that class? I'm getting an error saying object is not callable

Tags: python, import, python-3.2

## Student.py

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name="empty", year=0, GPA=1.0):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.GPA = GPA

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} is in year {1}, with a GPA of {2}.".format(self.name, self.year, self.GPA)
```

## Database.py

```
import Student 

s1 = Student("Joe", 2, 3.0)
```

Answer (score 8):

You're confusing the *module* `Student` with the *class* `Student`.  For example:

```
>>> import Student
>>> Student("Joe", 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

which makes sense, because it's the module:

```
>>> Student
<module 'Student' from './Student.py'>
```

To get at the class inside the module, you use the `objectname.membername` syntax:

```
>>> Student.Student
<class 'Student.Student'>
>>> Student.Student("Joe", 2, 3)
<Student.Student object at 0xb6f9f78c>
>>> print(Student.Student("Joe", 2, 3))
Joe is in year 2, with a GPA of 3.
```

Alternatively, you can import the class directly:

```
>>> from Student import Student
>>> Student
<class 'Student.Student'>
>>> print(Student("Joe", 2, 3))
Joe is in year 2, with a GPA of 3.
```